# should I erase by myself the pointer of an boost::ptr_vector?

Tags: c++, boost, memory-leaks, ptr-vector

I was wondering if this code leak :

`int main()

{

    boost::ptr_vector <char> v;

    v.push_back(new char[10]);

    v.clear()

}`

Will the ptr_vector destructor or clear() function delete the pointers it contains or do i have to do it myself?

Comment: `v.push_back(new char[10]);` I don't think this does what you think it does. Looking at the Boost documentation `push_back` only covers a single elements. (At any rate there'd be no way for the callee to know the size of your allocation.)

Comment: It's adding a dynamic char array to the ptr_vector. It's use in the code i'm reviewing and it works fine, but i'm not sure the memory is released.

Comment: @Ephemere: Following `new[]` with `delete` invokes undefined behavior. It's pure coincidence that it appears to work fine.

Comment: Also, it appears you simply want a `std::vector<std::string>`.

Comment: FredOverflow is right, try running your code through valgrind or something similar.

Comment: @FredOverflow: The char array is actually use as a byte array in the code, this is why string isn't use, otherwise it sure be my choice.

Comment: In that case, what's wrong with `std::vector<boost::array<char, 10> >`?

Answer (score -3):

From the vector documentation (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/~vector/):

> Vector destructor
>
> Destructs the container object. This
>   calls each of the contained element's
>   destructors, and deallocates all the
>   storage capacity allocated by the
>   vector.

delete[] won't be called, so it'll leak. And as other commenters pointed out, there are more STL ways to do it.

Comment: question is about `boost::ptr_vector`, not `std::vector`